# Why document.getElementsByClassName does not get the all elements exactly except for the first time?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with `n` items that I looped to create `n`  input buttons. Each input button has onclick function `typeItem()` that adds the clicked Item to a new array `typedItem[]` and makes that clicked item hidden and give it a new class `clicked`.

Then I have an upper Button with onclick function `undo()` which supposed to remove the hidden property and make those clicked items visible again.
I used the `document.getElementsByClassName` method to get the elements but it does not get all clicked elements except for the first time.

When I click more than 5 items randomly and trigger the `undo()` function, not all elements clicked reappear again. it misses one or more buttons especially from the second time after reloading the page...

Why that happens and how to fix it?? ...

```js
var arr = ["can", "san", "tan", "ban", "man", "yan", "fan", "van", "zan", "ran", "xan", "gan"];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('dv').innerHTML += "<input type='button' class='button' onclick='typeItem(this.value,this.id)' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
  document.getElementsByClassName('button')[i].id = "id" + i;
}

var typedItems = [];

function typeItem(val, idd) {
  document.getElementById(idd).style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById(idd).classList.add('clicked');
  typedItems.push(val);
}

function undo() {
  for (t = 0; t < typedItems.length; t++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("clicked")[t].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  typedItems = [];
};
```

```css
* {
  text-align: center
}

input,
button {
  margin: 3px;
  width: 23%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button style="background:orange" onclick="undo()">UnDo Button</button>

<br><br><br>

<p id="dv"></p>

<br>
<p id="dvv"></p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("clicked")[t].style.visibility = 'visible';` in that loop looks very inefficient - by the way, your code seems to work without the issue you describe (edit: oh, maybe not)

Comment: Why do you pass the value and id to `typeItem`? Just pass `this`, so you don't have to look the element up by ID.

Comment: do you want Undobutton to undo only the last one or all of buttons?

Comment: it seems the order you click the buttons is important ... which kind of leads to the very inefficient code you have in your undo function

Comment: It works well for the first time only, but after I click the undo button and then re click some random items and re click the undo again it does not work well. It leaves some items hidden

Comment: Your code assumes that the order of elements returned by `document.getElementsByClassName()` will be the same as their order in the `typedItems` array.

Comment: @sami Do you want to undo all buttons? when the undoButton is clicked? or only the last one, or all one by one with order?, we need to know these details to help you

Comment: Is there a reason why the `undo` function doesn't remove the `clicked` class?

Comment: I used `this` and it worked but with the same problem..
I want the Undobutton to undo the all buttons clicked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `undo()` function assumes that the elements in `typedItems` correspond to the elements with the `clicked` class.

This is true the first time that you call `undo()`. If you click `n` times, there will `n` elements with `class="clicked"` and `n` elements in the array,.

But it won't be true the next time. `undo()` empties the array, but it doesn't remove any of the `clicked` classes, it just makes the clicked elements visible.

So if you click 3 elements, click the undo button, and then click 3 different elements and click the undo button again, it will make the first 3 elements with the `clicked` class visible. But these won't necessarily be the same 3 elements you clicked the second time. `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns the elements in the order they appear in the DOM, not the order that you added the class.

Instead of looping over `typedItems`, you can loop over the elements with the class.

```
function undo() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".clicked").forEach(el => el.style.visibility = "visible");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to take the document.getElementsByClassName("clicked") out of your for loop.

```js
var arr = ["can", "san", "tan", "ban", "man", "yan", "fan", "van", "zan", "ran", "xan", "gan"];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('dv').innerHTML += "<input type='button' class='button' onclick='typeItem(this.value,this.id)' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
  document.getElementsByClassName('button')[i].id = "id" + i;
}

var typedItems = [];

function typeItem(val, idd) {
  document.getElementById(idd).style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById(idd).classList.add('clicked');
  typedItems.push(val);
}

function undo() {
  var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("clicked")
  for (let i = 0;i < hidden.length; i++) {    
    hidden[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  typedItems = [];
};
```

```css
* {
  text-align: center
}

input,
button {
  margin: 3px;
  width: 23%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button style="background:orange" onclick="undo()">UnDo Button</button>

<br><br><br>

<p id="dv"></p>

<br>
<p id="dvv"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```js
var arr = ["can","san","tan","ban","man","yan","fan","van","zan","ran","xan","gan"],
  container = document.querySelector("#b_container"),
  buttons = [];

arr.forEach(function(elem) {
  container.innerHTML += `<button>${elem}</button>`;
});

buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

document.querySelector("#b_container").onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    e.target.className = "b_hidden";
  }
}

document.querySelector("#b_undo").onclick = function() {
  buttons.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.className = "";
  });
}
```

```css
#b_undo {
  background-color: orange;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.b_hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="b_undo">UnDo Button</button>
<div id="b_container"></div>
```

Comment: why the second parameter **ind** in this function 
**arr.forEach(function(elem, ind)**??

when I removed it, It still works good

Comment: it's just the value of the iteration at the current call, I forgot to remove it, I have add it when I saw your for loop using `i` then I realised I don't need it, but forgot to remove it.. I have just edited the post.